# Beginner in Python - Password Generator with Condtionals not breaking while loop

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop, generator

I created a random password generator. With this generator is pulls from a variable of upper/lower case letters, numbers, and symbols and generates a random password.

The issue I'm having is I want to have a condition of 8 or more characters and if you don't request a long enough password it pops a message stating that it has to be at least 8 characters. The original creation of the generator would stop the code there and you would have to start all over. What I'm trying to do is use a while loop to ask the length again.

The issue I have come across is that my code is stuck in an infinite loop and will not break. When I do add a break I either get an error saying its out of a function or it just stops the code on input.

```py
import random

chars ="AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz1234567890!@#$%^&*"

length = input('How long would you like the password? ')
length = int(length)

if length < 8:
    print('Password must be at least 8 characters')
    while True:
        length = input('How long would you like your password?')
        length = int(length)
        break
        if length >= 8:
            num = input('How many passwords do you want?')
            num = int(num)
        

            for p in range(number_of_pass):
                password = 'Your password is: '
                for c in range(length):
                    password += random.choice(chars)
                print(password)
```

Comment: I ran this. If you enter a number less than 8, it will enter the loop (otherwise the program finishes). If you enter one greater, it allows you to enter another, but it never checks the condition, so you break immediately. Just to clarify : you said it ends up in an infinite loop, but is that the case, or is it not looping when it should?

Comment: Also, please make sure that your indentation on this site matches your indentation in the program itself. That may be why the program is running differently for each of us.